# unable to show text over the node in d3 force layout

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, svg

I'm not able to show the text on top of the node. The Text gets displayed underneath the node instead.

To be exact the node is hiding my test.

My code is as follows.....

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

<script src="../D3/d3.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <style>

        body {
            background-color: gray;
        }

</style>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        var width = 1400,
            height = 800;

        color = d3.scale.category10();

        var svg = d3.select("body")
                     .append("svg")
                     .attr("width", width)
                     .attr("height", height)
                     .attr("oncontextmenu", "return false;");


                    svg.append("svg:defs")
                    .selectAll("marker")
                    .data(["end"])
                    .enter().append("svg:marker")
                    .attr("id", String)
                    .attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
                    .attr("refX", 15)
                    .attr("refY", -1.5)
                    .attr("markerWidth", 6)
                    .attr("markerHeight", 6)
                    .attr("orient", "auto")
                    .append("svg:path")
                    .attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5");


 var nodes =
            [
     {
         "id": "Component",
         "description": "Component are the Containers",
         "type": "wiring"
     },
     {
         "id": "Form Design And Data Design",
         "description": "In the Form Design and Data Design we can create form and data",
         "type": "wiring"
     },
     {
         "id": "Data and Property ",
         "description": "All the Data has the Property and value Associated with It",
         "type": "wiring"
     },
     {
         "id": "Entity Query",
         "description": "Entity Queries can be used to create Entity Relationship ",
         "type": "wiring"
     },
     {
         "id": "Entity Query and Entity Data",
         "description": "Entity Data Can be used to create ",
         "type": "wiring"
     }
            ]


 var links = [
 ]



          var texts = svg.selectAll(".text")
                       .data(nodes)
                       .enter()
                       .append("text")
                       .attr("x", 50)
                       .attr("y", 40)
                       .attr("fill","white")
                       .attr("font-family","sans-serif")
                       .attr("font-size","15px")
                       .text(function (d) { return d.id;});



          var force = d3.layout.force()
                      .nodes(nodes)
                      .links(links)
                      .size([width, height])
                      .linkDistance(250)
                      .charge(-1000)
                      .gravity(.1)
                      //.charge(-10 / k)
                     // .gravity(100 * k)
                      //.linkStrength(5)
                      .theta(1)
                      .alpha(3)
                      //.on('tick', tick)
                      .start();




          var edges = svg.selectAll("line")
                        .data(links)
                        .enter()
                        .append("line")
                        .style("stroke", "#ccc")
                        .style("stroke-width", 1)
                        .attr("marker-end", "url(#end)");


          var nodes = svg.selectAll(".rect")
                        .data(nodes)
                        .enter()
                        .append("svg:rect")
                        .attr("width", 150)
                        .attr("height", 50)
                        .attr("rx", 10)
                        .attr("ry", 10)
                        .attr("x", 150)
                        .attr("y",160)

                        .style("fill", function(d,i) { return color(i); })
                        .call(force.drag);




          force.on("tick", function() 
          {
              edges.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
                   .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
                   .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
                   .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });
              nodes.attr("x", function(d) { return d.x; })
                   .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y; })
              texts.attr("transform", function (d)
              {
                  return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
              });
          });






    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move the text creation to be later in the file, i.e after the node creation.

SVG uses a painters model so objects later in the file are drawn on top of objects earlier in the file. Just like a painter overpaints earlier things with later things.

Answer (score 2):

First rename your var nodes to nodesdata

```
var nodesdata =
            [
     {
         "id": "Component",
         "description": "Component are the Containers",
         "type": "wiring"
     },
     {
         "id": "Form Design And Data Design",
         "description": "In the Form Design and Data Design we can create form and data",
         "type": "wiring"
     },
     {
         "id": "Data and Property ",
         "description": "All the Data has the Property and value Associated with It",
         "type": "wiring"
     },
     {
         "id": "Entity Query",
         "description": "Entity Queries can be used to create Entity Relationship ",
         "type": "wiring"
     },
     {
         "id": "Entity Query and Entity Data",
         "description": "Entity Data Can be used to create ",
         "type": "wiring"
     }
            ]
```

So now the data associated with node will become:

```
var nodes = svg.selectAll(".rect")
                        .data(nodesdata)
```

Next make text after the nodes are created:

```
var texts = svg.selectAll(".text")
                       .data(nodesdata)
                       .enter()
                       .append("text")
                       .attr("x", 50)
                       .attr("y", 40)
                       .attr("fill","white")
                       .attr("font-family","sans-serif")
                       .attr("font-size","15px")
                       .text(function (d) { return d.id;});
```

working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/cxgM7bFMnIbUVslepOTR?p=preview)

Comment: It works..thanks a lot  Cyril...Can you please tell me what is wrong in my code..Just to learn for no future mistake .....

Comment: the problem is that in SVG there is no zindex so to show text on top of nodes we first make nodes or circles and then make text, thus text will appear on top of nodes.

Comment: That's Really Explains a lot to me as a fresher in D3.js...Thanks a lot once again..will get back to  you if I have any doubts further...If you don,t mind Can u  please tell me how to initiate a chat process....in Stack Overflow....

Comment: Hi Cyril..I have one more question..I'm sorry I'm not able to ask another question,since SO block my questioning for 4 days..so I'm asking via comments..Can you please help me to add Tool tip to my node for displaying contents in description in my [nodesdata].....

Comment: this can help you http://www.coppelia.io/2014/07/an-a-to-z-of-extra-features-for-the-d3-force-layout/ see tooltip section